# Typescript 2.0 tsc.exe code 1 error (after upgrade)

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I'm making my project in VS2015 with angular2 in typescript. Occasionaly i've encountered error:
error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "tsc.exe". Illegal characters in path. 
I don't remember how i got over it last time, i supposed it disappeared without my interaction. But today this error doesn't want to go away.
I installed TS 2.0 RC because i thought it was a bug and it had been fixed in new version. But now i get `error
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 1. MGMS.Web C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 222`

Can you help me with this ?

Here is my diagnostic log
http://www.filedropper.com/diagnosticlog

and project
http://www.filedropper.com/project_11

[04.09.2016]
I tried to figure it out and changed the Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file to use hardcoded value 1.8 of the tools. It worked. I don't know how because before installation of Typescript 2.0 it didn't work as well but now it worked. To be sure it works for all my team members i added two lines in xproj

`<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <TypeScriptNuGetToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptNuGetToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>`

I also tried to run continous integration on my solution in visualstudioonline. But here it doesn't work with the same error 1 of tsc.exe. It's funny because the log shows me that visualstudioonline correctly uses tsc.exe in version 1.8. What is going on guys ?

I tried running tsc.exe v2.0 from command line and it shows error like in first diagnostic log.

Comment: Have you found a solution yourself? I facing the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Meantime new version of tsc compiler came out. It was problem only with specific installation(dont know why). Clean system + clean installation solved problem.